# Kubuntu: How can I disable password prompts when updating or installing software?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, password

I'd like to disable the prompt that comes up when updating software in KDE Discover. I'm already a member of group `sudo` with the following line in sudoers: `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`.

When running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, I don't get asked for a password. However, when installing or updating applications in Discover I do.

How can I disable this password authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note this is for Kubuntu. I haven't tested it on Ubuntu, and the file to change is probably different, although it's probably in the same directory.)

1. Open a terminal emulator and switch to root (`sudo -i` or `su root`).
2. Run `cd /usr/share/polkit-1/actions`.
3. Make a backup of the file you are about to change: run `cp org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.policy org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.policy.bak`.
4. Edit the policy file: `nano org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.policy`.
5. In the policy file, find the section with the id `org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.commitchanges`. Change the text between `<allow_active>` and `</allow_active>` from `auth_admin_keep` to `yes`. You can also apply this change to `org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.writefiletodisk` if you want to enable passwordless changes to system settings.
6. Save and exit by pressing CTRL+X and then Y.
7. Repeat for `org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-update` in `org.freedesktop.packagekit.policy`: first back up the file, then find ID `org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-update`, and under it, change from `<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>` to `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>`
8. You should now be able to install or update software without a password!